# Why mock patch not works as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, stub

**b.py:**

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def hello():
    print("hello")
    return 1

@patch("b.hello", return_value="wow")
def fun(mock_hello):
    print(hello())

print("start")
fun()
print("end")
```

I use python3:

```
pie@pie:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

For above code, I expect to get next because I have mocked `hello`:

```
start
wow
end
```

But actually, I got next:

```
pie@pie:~$ python3 b.py
start
start
wow
end
hello
1
end
```

I have totally confused by the mock behavior, what happened?

Comment: You are using it as `hello` and you have to patch it as `hello`, not as `b.hello`.

Comment: @KlausD. I change to `@patch("hello", return_value="wow")`, but it show next error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1397, in _get_target
    target, attribute = target.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 8, in <module>
    @patch("hello", return_value="wow")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1548, in patch
    getter, attribute = _get_target(target)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1400, in _get_target
    (target,))
TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'hello'`. I guess I made something wrong, could you paste a full answer, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the answer in case anyone interested, the root cause is `patch target` and `patch` in same file. There won't have any issue if not in the same file.

From the sourcecode of `patch function` in `unittest/mock.py`, we could see in fact it use `__import__` to import the target:

`patch` -> `getter, attribute = _get_target(target)` -> `getter = lambda: _importer(target)` -> `thing = __import__(import_path)`

So above code in question behave as next:

1. As top level script `b.py` start, it first print `start`
2. As top level script, it call `fun()`, at this point, the `patch` will use `__import__` to import `b.hello`. So `b.py` now act as a python module which be executed again. As a python module, it print `start`.
3. As python module, it call `fun`, as module already imported, so this won't start another import. As a module run, `hello()` really means `b.hello()`, which already patched, it should returns `wow`. So, `wow` now be printed.
4. As python module, it finally print `end`.
5. Now python module executed finish, `b.py` as a top level script continue run `hello()`, but now the `patch` indeed patched `b.hello`, not `hello`, so it still print `hello` & `1`.
6. Finally, as python top level script it print `end`.